# Color based on statement

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I am making a `form` in which it saves the **creation date**.
And I want to make a **color** change depending on the date.

Example:

> 1 day ago: green
>
> 2 days ago: yellow
>
> 3 days ago: red

```
<?php
   while ($registro = mysql_fetch_object($consulta)) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>$registro->consulid</td>";
      echo "<td>$registro->consultatipo</td>";
      echo "<td>$registro->fechacreada</td>";
      echo "<td><div id='color'></div></td>";
      echo "<td><a href='consultar.php?idconsulta=$registro->consulid&fecha=$registro->fechacreada&tipoc=$registro->consultatipo'> <img src='IMG/edit.png' height='20' border='0px' width='20'> </a></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
   }
   mysql_close($conexion);
?>
```

I've this code and i want to add the color on the div color and the paramater date is  `$registro->fechacreada`

My question is how i do it on JavaSript?

Comment: nice idea, what have you tried?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: If you would like help with your code, post some of it so we can see it and give advice. Also please read a [guide to asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a field called `inTime` and set it with the value stored in `JavaScript` variable `time` by executing this code `var time = new Date().getTime();` function in JavaScript at the time of insertion of data.
Then when fetching data, Check that

```
var a = new Date().getTime();
if(a >= ($time)+86400000 && a< ($time)+172800000){
  // 1 day old
  // color code here
}
else
if(a >= ($time)+172800000){
  // older than 1 day
}
```

Note that `($time)` should be replaced with value of `inTime` field in table